# Rendering logs from Mongodb into flask route

Tags: python, mongodb, logging, flask

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb:xxxx")
db = client.databasename
collection = db.logs    

@app.route('/log')
def Results():
    try:
        loggings = db.collection.find()
        return render_template('index.html', loggings=loggings)
    except Exception as e:
        return dumps({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   app.run(debug = True)
```

This is my code for app.py and for 'index.html', my code looks like

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        {% for message in logs %}
            <h3>{{message}}</h3>
        {%endfor%}
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, it does not display anything on the localhost:xxxx/log route.

May I know why?
Thanks!

Comment: you send data as `loggings=` so in template you have to use `... in loggings`, not `...in log`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `loggings=` in

```
render_template('index.html', loggings=loggings)
```

then you have to use `loggings` also in template

```
{% for message in loggings %}
```

but you use `{% ... in logs %}`

Comment: Thank you so much, now I have logs displayed but not formatted at all. May I know if there is any way to use like 'tables' to format them? Or any other way to format them nicely? Thank you so much!

Comment: you have your template for this - if message has many fields then display every field separatelly - ie. `{{ message.id }}` or `{{ message["id"] }}` . And then you can put it in different tag and style `HTML` using `CSS`. If you have strings in messages then you can edit them in `Results()` before you send to `template`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm trying to create a table. Then, the content of each row/column will be loggings.id or message.id? Am I approaching in a right way for the table?

Comment: I don't know what columns you have in databases but if you have columns ie. `id`and `text` then `message.id` will give cell in row from column `id`, `message.text` will give cell from column `text`, etc. so you can do `<tr><td>{{ message.id }}</td><td>{{ message.text }}</td></tr>` to create row in `<table>`

Comment: So I need to keep the original index.html that I posted in the question? If yes, where should the table (<tr><td>) part fit at? And I have thousands of logs.. Will it still fit in the table format without any other special formatting? Thanks!

Comment: You should use it instead of `{{ message }}`. I don't know what you have in database so I don't know if it will fit. But for many data all web pages use pagination. You run get from database only few rows and add in template button to load next page with next rows - you can use urls like `'/log?page=1` (or `'/log?offset=100`)  and get this value with `request.args.get("page")` (or `request.args.get("offset")`).

Comment: `<style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;    
    }
    </style>
<table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>method</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
 {%for m in loggings%}
      <td>{{m.timestamp}}</td>
      <td>{{m.thread}}</td>
      <td>{{m.message}}</td>
 {%endfor%}
    </tr>

  </table>
` I can get it but logs are displayed horizontally instead of downwards.. May I know why? This is my final step..

Comment: you put all in one `<tr></tr>` but every row has to be in own `<tr></tr>` (`tr` means `table row`) so you have to use `<tr></tr>` inside `for`-loop